# How can I make a phylogenetic tree with both continuous and categorical variables

Tags: r, phylogeny, ape-phylo

I have a dataset which consists of 89 specimens, these are placed into clades as shown in the table below as an example. They also have 5 continuous variables, my aim is to create a phylogenetic tree of this data in R but im not too sure how to go about it. The continuous data has been standardised/normalised.

| Specimen | Type_1 | Type_2 | Type_3 | Cont1 | Cont2 | Cont3 | Cont4 | Cont5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sauro | eusauro | sauro_1 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 7 | 8 |
| 2 | thera | rapt | manirap | 2 | 5 | 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | orni | basal_orn | basal_orn | 9 | 10 | 15 | 20 | 4 |

so the table is really simple and small but its to give an idea of what my data set looks like. How can i use this data to create a phylogenetic tree on R. I primarily want the tree to be split up according to the types and plan to use the Cont1, Cont2 etc to alter branch lengths manually

Comment: This is a reasonable question but there isn't very much phylogenetic expertise on StackOverflow.  If you don't get an answer here (as seems likely) I would try on `r-sig-phylo@r-project.org` ... (if you do cross-post, either delete this question or include a link to it in your mailing list post)

Answer (score 0):

So I've figured it out sort of the long tedious way but it works the code is psoted below.

```
mytreenew<- ape::read.tree(text = '(Hetero,((Kentro,(Tuo,(Stenops))),(Dyoplo,((psitto1, psitto2, psitt3,(korea,(aurora,(lepto1, lepto2,(Centro))))),(Diluvi,(Tenon1, Tenon2,(Campto,(Iguano, Our1, Our2,(Tethy, (Magna, (Lambeo, (Cory,(Gobi1, Gobi2))))))))))))),((Plateo,(lufengo,((Mamenchi1, mamenchi2), (omei1, omei2, omei3),((Apato1,Apato2,(diplo, seismosaurus)),(Camar,((Giraffatitan,(Lusotitan,(Huabei,(Astropho,(Patago))))),(Tasta,(Opistho1,Opishto2,((Moz, Dread)))))))))));')
plot(mytreenew)
```